# <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'My-Library-Name'

Tags: python, postgresql, web2py, web2py-modules

I'm writing a query code in controller:

```
books=db(db.book.lib_name=="My-Library-Name").select(db.book.title, db.book.ISBN, orderby=db.book.title)
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'> invalid literal for long() with base 10: "My-Library-Name"
```

This is my DAL database(I am using postgresql as my database driver):

```
db = DAL('postgres://myUsername:myPassword@localhost/libman',pool_size=0)
db.define_table('library',
            Field('lib_name', ondelete='CASCADE', unique=True),
            Field('address', length=20),
            primarykey=['lib_name'])

db.define_table('book',
                Field('ISBN', unique=True, ondelete='CASCADE'),
                Field('lib_name', 'reference library'),
                Field('pic', 'upload'),
                Field('title', length=100),
                Field('publisher_lname', length=50),
                Field('publisher_fname', length=50),
                Field('no_of_copies', 'integer'),
                Field('available_copies', 'integer'),
                Field('description', length=255),
                primarykey=['ISBN'])
```

Thanks in Advance for the respond

Comment: `"My-Library-Name"` is not a number

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I did not specify my lib_name field as integer or long. By default it is a string. But why?

Comment: This is happening above PostgreSQL its self, in your app's data access code.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thank you for that answer. But how do I fix it?

Comment: @JalalAgantal If I knew that, it'd be an answer not a comment. All I'm saying is "this doesn't look like a PostgreSQL issue". Presumably it's something in web2py, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

lib-name is a foreign key, so it is not a valid query. Query could be based on db.book.ISBN instead.

On the other hand I suggest to change your model to:

```
db.define_table('library',
        Field('lib_name', ondelete='CASCADE', unique=True),
        Field('address', length=20),
        migrate=True,
        )

db.define_table('book',
            Field('ISBN', unique=True, ondelete='CASCADE'),
            Field('lib_name', 'reference library'),
            Field('pic', 'upload'),
            Field('title', length=100),
            Field('publisher_lname', length=50),
            Field('publisher_fname', length=50),
            Field('no_of_copies', 'integer'),
            Field('available_copies', 'integer'),
            Field('description', length=255),
            migrate=True,
            )
```

Since primarykey is intended to connect to [legacy DB](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#markmin_LegacyDatabases). Dont know if this is your case